# Overcounting in an elementary exercise

Tags: combinatorics

I can't tell what's being overcounted in the following example.

> A student is to answer 7 of the 10 questions on a test. How many choices does she have? What if she must answer at least 3 of the first 5 questions?

The answer to the first is clearly $_{10}\text C_7=120$. To answer the second, I first choose 3 among the first 5 questions, and then choose 4 of the remaining 7. This gives me $_5\text C_3\times\,_7\text C_4=350$.

Wait, no, that can't be right.

The actual answer is to consider each case separately. First case is only 3 of the first 5 questions are chosen. Second case is 4 of the first 5 are chosen. Third case is all 5 of the first 5 are chosen. Then $_5\text C_3\times\,_5\text C_4+\,_5\text C_4\times\,_5\text C_3+\,_5\text C_5\times\,_5\text C_2=110$.

My question is: **What is being overcounted in my first attempt?**

Comment: Congrats for having asked the $400000$th question, btw. ;-)

Comment: I'm so honored.

Comment: As you should indeed be.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: Why did you delete your answer? It is indeed the problem in OP's method - "choose $4$ out of the remaining $7$" when there are only $5$ remaining.

Comment: Your last solution is correct. What you 'overcount' is in fact an overlap between 'first five qustions' and 'any 7 questions'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose e.g. she answers questions $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$.  Which were the "3 among the first 5", and which were the "4 of the remaining 7"?

Comment: I don't understand. The process as I see it is choose $3$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, mark the unchosen as $a,b$, then choose $4$ of $\{a,b,6,7,8,9,10\}$.

Comment: How did you choose those three?

Comment: @ok_: You're counting this example both as "first choose 1,2,3 then choose 4,5,6,7" and as "first choose 1,2,4 then choose 3,5,6,7", for example.

Comment: Oh, OK! That makes sense now.